# How to write xml files to hdfs using spark

Tags: xml, apache-spark

I'm planning to read data from hbase, doing some simple operation and write the output in xml files to hdfs. Is it possible to do in spark?I managed to read hbase data into RDD now, and don't know what's next. I'm new to spark ,any help will be appreciated. BTW, I'm using Java.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is XML required? This is a highly inefficient format. For example, the Apache Parquet format is much easier to read and write using Spark.